# How to get reason of deprecated attribute using libclang

Tags: c++, libclang

I am writing a tool that needs to inspect C++ header files. For this I use libclang (actually ClangSharp, which is a .NET wrapper around libclang, but that wrapper is mapping the native types directly onto .NET types). The current version uses libclang version 16.0.6.

I have constructs in the code as follows:

```
#define ENUM_DATA_TYPE "This enumeration"
#define DEPRECATED_TEXT " should not be used anymore"
#define DEPRECATED_ENUM [[deprecated(ENUM_DATA_TYPE DEPRECATED_TEXT)]]
enum DEPRECATED_ENUM DoNotUseMe
{
    Value = 1
}
```

For the analysis I want to get the text "This enumeration should not be used anymore" from the attribute using libclang, but I can't seem to get that done.

What I do is that I retrieve the attributes of the declaration (this is C# code, but the mechanism and the names of the libclang datatypes are the same in C++):

```
string GetDeprecatedText(Decl decl)
{
    string deprecatedText = null;

    foreach (Attr attribute in decl.Attrs)
    {
        if (CX_AttrKind.CX_AttrKind_Deprecated == attribute.Kind)
        {
            // What should I do here to get the text??
        }
    }

    return deprecatedText;
}
```

The actual object type seems to be an [`InheritableAttr`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1InheritableAttr.html), but none of the methods for that class (or any of its base classes) will give me the opportunity to retrieve the deprecation reason.

The `Attr` object does give me a lot of information of where the attribute occurs in the original code. However, then I have the following challenges:

1. Given the source location: how can I get the original text from that location, without reading the file again and parsing it myself?
2. When I have the name of the macro being used in that location, I can find the `MacroDefinitionRecord` for it. With this object, how can I get the fully expanded text for that macro?

My preference would be to be able to get the reason directly from the attribute, but if that is not possible, I would like some guidance in trying to get the information myself via the macro definition.

Comment: Can you try `getAttrName()` in `InheritableAttr`?

Comment: @kiner_shah That method does not seem to exist (cannot find it either in de libclang documentation)

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1InheritableAttr.html - Here go to "Public member functions inherited from clang::AttributeCommonInfo" section, there you should find it.

Comment: @kiner_shah `getAttrName` just returns "deprecated".  Do you see different behavior?

Comment: Clang has a C++ API called "libtooling" and a C API called "libclang".  From what I can tell, ClangSharp exposes a mix of both.  Which API exactly are you wanting to do this with?  It's possible using libtooling, appears impossible with libclang, and I don't know about ClangSharp, but I suspect it is also impossible there.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak, I didn't try this actually. But it seemed it would print out the entire name, I was probably wrong then.

Comment: @kiner_shah I now see the getAttrName. But that method indeed just returns the actual NAME of the attribute (i.e. "deprecated") and not something I can deduce the reason from.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak I guess in the case of ClangSharp I do not have an option to choose the API. In the C/C++ world I would choose the libtooling API, but I can only go forward when ClangSharp also exposes it then?

Comment: I'm not sure that ClangSharp does not expose it, but in my brief search I was unable to locate it.  But the main point of my comment is to request clarification on the scope of the question: are you intending to ask about libtooling, libclang, or ClangSharp?  The title says libclang, while the text is about ClangSharp.  It's difficult to attempt an answer without that clarification.